# Android application output verbosity with Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac

Every time I deploy Xamarin Forms to Android I get approximately 1000 [mono-assembly] messages

In the Project / Build settings, I have set the requisite option to 'Quiet'

I have also implemented an environment.txt file with following

```
MONO_LOG_LEVEL=error
MONO_LOG_MASK=gc
```

In spite of this, I cannot get rid of these messages

```
 [monodroid-assembly]     ZIP: local header offset: 35499804; data offset: 35499912; file size: 1683384
 [monodroid-assembly] /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-kjbSvJffIh6KuLyEXW4fQQ==/base.apk entry: assemblies/netstandard.dll
 [monodroid-assembly]     ZIP: local header offset: 37183296; data offset: 37183408; file size: 90624
 [monodroid-assembly] /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-kjbSvJffIh6KuLyEXW4fQQ==/base.apk entry: typemap.jm
 [monodroid-assembly]     ZIP: local header offset: 37274032; data offset: 37274128; file size: 1304780
 [monodroid-assembly] /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-kjbSvJffIh6KuLyEXW4fQQ==/base.apk entry: typemap.mj
```

Please can advise what am doing wrong?

Comment: It's a known issue reported here :https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24556/setting-msbuild-project-build-output-verbosity-to.html  , consider raising issue on msbuild github site: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/

Comment: Hi @Journeyman1234, did you finally open an issue ?
If yes, can you please provide the issue link ?